# Are there English equivalents to Japanese and Chinese proverb meaning “sell dog meat by displaying the head of lamb?

Tags: proverbs

The saying, “A pig in a poke” quoted in Maureen Dowd's article in New York Times (August 10) referring to Donald Trump’s incendiary remarks in Presidential campaign debate 
(See https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi?) reminded me of a popular Japanese proverb – Yoto kuniku, which is a direct translation of Chinese proverb, gua yan tou mai gourou-“sell dog meat by displaying the head of lamb at the store-front,” meaning a crooked business practice.

I think “A pig in a poke” and “sell dog meat by displaying the head of lamb” are similar in spirit, however, the former hides the pig, the latter on the contrary shows off a false bait, namely false description of contents in legal terms.

Are there any English counterparts to Japanese / Chinese saying, “Sell dog meat by displaying the head of lamb”?

Comment: This practice is called ***bait and switch***  but I can’t think of a saying that advises someone on *how* to do it.

Comment: [**Sell the sizzle, not the steak**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUmxGqsuKmY).

Comment: "Sell a bill of goods" http://www.word-detective.com/2013/05/bill-of-goods/

Comment: I always suspected things about the local Chinese takeaway, but I never knew they had an expression about it! :)

Comment: The point about the pig in the poke is that it might not be a pig at all. The seller tells the buyer it's a pig and he buys it without checking.

Comment: In the Japanese/Chinese proverb, does the buyer know they are buying dog meat when they buy it? If yes, then it is a bait-and-switch, but if no, then it is fraud.

Answer (score 6):

*Bait-and-switch* is a common expression for appearing to offer one thing yet selling another.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me a little of ***mutton dressed as lamb*** which can result in a slap in the face if said within earshot of any number of 'older' females.

Comment: It's a likely to be muttered *by* ‘older’ females, in my limited experience.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I can think of is *window dressing*, the second meaning:

> the act of decorating and arranging products to display in a store
>   window
>
> something that is intended to make a person or thing seem better or
>   more attractive but that does not have any real importance or effect

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/window%20dressing)